# Tableau Yearly Difference

Tags: tableau-desktop

How can I calculate year difference in Tableau, while still showing the year total?
I know I can use the table calculation, but this changes the year data

[image: Result Wanted]

[image: Table Calculation]

Answer (score 1):

Drag Year over Columns and measure names onto rows.
On Measure names keep only sales. Turn SUM(Sales) into difference
and drag sum(sales) on measure values shelf.
[image: Sales Dif over Sales]